# × TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I try to run this code it gives me this error:

> × TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Why does it happen? How can I make it work?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Product from './Product/Product';
import useStyles from './styles';

const products = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Shoes', description: 'Running Shoes.' },
  {id: 2, name: 'MacBook', description: 'Apple MacBook.' },
];

const Products = ({ products }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products.map((products) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product />
          </Grid>
        ))};
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Comment: First time I see this error in its new wording on SO ^^ still feels unreal that this super-common error message was changed due to a bug I opened with v8. For people unaware of it: it means exactly the same as `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` did.

Comment: The message change will obscure many years of error message search results.  @CherryDT Interesting bug you found originally though.

Comment: @CherryDT what was the original bug? Have a link to the GH issue? I would be interested to see the history of this change

Comment: @no_stack_dub_sack https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11365

Answer (score 149):

I had the same error and solved it by first asking if the array existed.

Example:

```
<Filter>
  { product.color?.map((c) => (
    <FilterColor color = {c} key = {c} />
  ))};
</Filter>
```

Comment: Yes... but why does this work?

Comment: `product.color?` checks if `product.color` exists and maps only then over the array.

Comment: @Trees4theForest it’s a known “Safe Navigation Operator”, which makes sure that we will not get null and/or undefined values, can be used to prevent from throwing errors, when trying to access object properties of an object that don’t exist. 
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator)

Comment: Insteed of this, it will also work  { product.color && product.color.map((c) => (
    <FilterColor color = {c} key = {c} />
  ))};

Answer (score 17):

There is a property "products" in your component. That variable has higher priority than the map you have outside, and your `.map` is using it. I would recommend to rename one of them, to avoid variables with the same name.

Given the error, I would guess that that property wasn't passed to the component.

Also, the parameter of the map lambda is "products" too. Change it to "product", or it will fail.

Comment: You can see these issues clearly in the following replication: https://codesandbox.io/s/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map-00jv1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 13):

You are getting a blank array[]. For this, you are facing this error. You can solve this problem two ways:

```
{products && products.map((product) => (
    <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Product/>
    </Grid>
))};
```

Or

```
{products?.map((product) => (
    <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Product/>
    </Grid>
))};
```

Answer (score 7):

The properties, `products`, that you're passing to your component (`Products`) are undefined. The *Map* method is taking in account the `products` that you have passed as properties is not the one that you have created outside the component itself.

If you want to map out the `products` array that you created outside of your components then just change its name as the array has the same name as the properties passed. If you want to use the `products` (from the property) then make sure that you're passing the properties in the component.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you have taken the array "products" and the map item "products" by the same name. Change the map item to something else like "product":

```
const products = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Shoes', description: 'Running Shoes.' },
        {id: 2, name: 'MacBook', description: 'Apple MacBook.' },
    ];

const Products = ({ products }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product/>
          </Grid>
        ))};
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
const Products = ({ products }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products && products.map((products) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product />
          </Grid>
        ))};
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Just add "`products &&`". This will check if the map is defined or not.

Answer (score 3):

Write it in this way and the issue would be resolved:

```
<Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
  {products ?.map((product) => (
    <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
      <Product/>
    </Grid>
  ))};
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```js
 { product.color?.map((c) => (
    <FilterColor color = {c} key = {c} />
  ))};
```

This would fix the issue, but why does it appear well behind the scene? React won't update the state immediately. This concept is called scheduling, and that is why when you access *products.map*, *products* are an empty array.

Comment: Does this answer make any sense?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to pass the products properties into the *Product* component. Change this:

```
{products.map((products) => (
              <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                <Product/>
```

to this:

```
{products.map((products) => (
              <Grid item key={products.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                <Product/>
```

Why? Because you're mapping an object (*products*) into a JSX element in your case which is the <Product/> component, so using { product.id } you're trying map an undefined object.
Then make sure the *products* property you're trying to map out, is correctly passed into the parent component using the *Products* component.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add loading into user page - use useState

```
{const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);}
```

Step 2: Set loading value to false at the end of async fetch function.
If you’re using the *try-catch* method, put this code line inside the try method:

```
  {   setLoading(false)}
```

Step 3: Use a unary operation in the inside the render() part of the code

```
{ loading ? (
  <h2>loading</h2>
) :  {/* Enter code here */}}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, please check that products are exported. If yes, then change

```js
{products.map((products) => (
  <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
  <Product/>
```

to

```js
{products.map((products) => (
   <Grid item key={products.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
   <Product/>
```

Because here you map products as products, so you have to set the key like `products.id`.

Comment: Perhaps mark the literal parts with italics (so it is clear what is and what isn't literal)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

You had named each iteration of the map method with products, but you are using product to catch each instance of the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You should basically check the values received are undefined or not.

In [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)), you can use something like this: `{{person?.name}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the map part like this:

```
{(products|| []).map(product) => ( // Your code ))}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's Brillant, I was having similar issue and your solution  works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
    {products && products.map((products) => (
      <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
        <Product />
      </Grid>
    ))};
  </Grid>
```

Here changes in **products && products.map()** instead of **products.map()**.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure properties is not undefined.

```
typeof products.map() !== undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Just use 
{products && products.map((products) => (
       <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
     <Product />
   </Grid>
))};

// add "products &&" before the map method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        {products && products.map((product) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product />
          </Grid>
        ))};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I had a similar problem which this approach solved.  Although unlike the hard coded `products` array in this question I was fetching an array of data from a database.  Anyway, the idea is that `products && products.map(.....` is first checking to make sure that `products` isn't undefined (or has a truthy value at least).  If it's undefined, the `products.map` won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it gives an error when you haven't used the variable of useState.

And I have made two other components. 1) Tour 2) Tours

```
 const [tours, setTours ] = useState([]);
```

Now, I have used this **tours** variable in App.js file using Tours components.

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVOv4.jpg)

I have used **tours** in the *App.js* file.

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWWc8.png)

Now, I'm taking the tours variable for using the .map() function in the *Tours.js* file.

```
const Tours = ({ tours }) => {
/...
{tours.map()
.../
```

[Tours.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa3CM.jpg)

You have to check that both files have the same spelling. Otherwise, it gives an error and also doesn’t work the UI of that particular file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```js
{products.map((product) => (
  <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
    <Product/>
  </Grid>
))};
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You had this kind of error because you don't pass any information (props) inside the product component. So try this:

```
return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products.map((products) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Grid>
        ))};
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Products = ({ products }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products?.map((products) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product />
          </Grid>
        ))};
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while working on a mongodb restful api with Node and express; specifically for my post method:

```
    router.post('/post', async (req, res) => {
    const data = new Model({
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age
    })

    try{
        const dataToSave = await data.save()
        res.status(200).json(dataToSave)
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message})
    }
})
```

Got this error message:

```
D:\coding\MongoDB\restful_project\routes\routes.js:12
    name: req.body.name,
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

What fixed it for me was installing a json parser; I used BodyParser

```
npm i body-parser
```

Then I added the bodyParser.json() function into the post method, and it worked after trying it on Postman

```
router.post('/post', bodyParser.json(), async (req, res) => {
const data = new Model({
    name: req.body.name,
    age: req.body.age
})

try{
    const dataToSave = await data.save()
    res.status(200).json(dataToSave)
}
catch(error){
    res.status(400).json({message: error.message})
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

> This is works for me

```
           {categories.data?.map((item)=>(
            <div key={item.id} className="category">
                <img src={cat1} alt="" />
            </div>))}
```

Answer (score 0):

when I am using this shows a name error

```
{
    ListofRestaurant.restaurants?.map((res)=>(
                    <RestaurantCard data={res} key={res.info.id} />
                ))
               }
```

When I store in a variable.the error gone

```
enter code here
 const arr = resObj?.restaurants
const[ListofRestaurant, setListofRestaurant]=useState(arr);
    {
        ListofRestaurant.map((res)=>(
                        <RestaurantCard data={res} key={res.info.id} />
                    ))
                   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check INITIAL_STATE in the reducer.

You must specify an array in the ID object you are calling in the reducer.

Example:

```
const INTIAL_STATE = {
    products: [],
    product: { name: "", brand_name: "", prices: "", color: "", images: []},
    error: "",
}

product.images.map(img => {
    return(
        <div key = {img.id} className = "img-itemm">
            <img src = {img.image} alt = {img.image} />
        </div>
    )
})
```