# React submenus from an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

So i've made this navbar:

[image: Looks like this]

the navbar gets parameters such as URL, parentId from an array.
All countys in the array have a non unique Id called parent which is equal to '1'.
All towns have a non unique Id called parent which ranges from 2-22.
In the case below Blekinge and Dalarna are countys (parent='1'), and their corresponding towns comes after in the array parent='2' are blekinge county towns and parent='3' are dalarna county towns. Below is a snippet of the array of countys and towns in sweden.

```
const orter = [{
        "id": "2",
        "rubrik": "Blekinge",
        "url": "blekinge",
        "parent": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "23",
        "rubrik": "Karlshamn",
        "url": "blekinge/karlshamn",
        "parent": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "24",
        "rubrik": "Karlskrona",
        "url": "blekinge/karlskrona",
        "parent": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "25",
        "rubrik": "Olofström",
        "url": "blekinge/olofstrom",
        "parent": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "26",
        "rubrik": "Ronneby",
        "url": "blekinge/ronneby",
        "parent": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "27",
        "rubrik": "Sölvesborg",
        "url": "blekinge/solvesborg",
        "parent": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "rubrik": "Dalarna",
        "url": "dalarna",
        "parent": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "28",
        "rubrik": "Älvdalen",
        "url": "dalarna/alvdalen",
        "parent": "3"
    },
    {
        "id": "29",
        "rubrik": "Avesta",
        "url": "dalarna/avesta",
        "parent": "3"
    },
    {
        "id": "318",
        "rubrik": "Borlänge",
        "url": "dalarna/borlange",
        "parent": "3"
    }]
export default orter
```

I want the sub-menu for each county to be populated with the corresponding towns.
But I cant get this to work, what happens is instead that each county and town gets their own nav-link item and sub-menu item. I have tried mixing arround with if statements but I just cant wrap my head around it.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './nav.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import orter from '../../data/orter'

const Nav = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
    
    const ort = orter.map((obj, key) =>{
        return (
                <ul className="nav-links">
                        <li 
                        parentid={obj.parent}
                        key={key}
                        >
                        <Link
                         to={obj.url}>
                            <i class='knapp'>#</i>
                            <span className="link_name">{obj.rubrik}</span>
                            <i className="arrow" onClick={()=> setToggle(!toggle)}>N</i>
                        </Link>
                        {toggle &&(
                            <ul className="sub-menu">
                            <li parentid={obj.parent}>
                                <Link
                                to={obj.url}>{obj.rubrik}</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        )}
                    </li>
                </ul>
        )
    })
    return (
        <div className='sidebar'>
            {ort}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

And here is the css

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.sidebar{
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:260px;
    background: #ea5526;
}
.arrow{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.sidebar .logo-details{
    height:60px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.sidebar .logo-details i{
    font-size: 30px;
    color:#fff;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name
{
    font-size: 30px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.sidebar .nav-links{
    background: #ea5526;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover{
    background: #f9712d;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color:#fff;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu{
    padding: 6px 6px 14px 80px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: #f9712d;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu{
    display:block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
    position: absolute;
    left:100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating the overall flat structure of `orter` array, so no links are nested under a parent link.

Create a function to process the flat array structure an create a tree of links.

```
const createLinks = (links) =>
  Object.values(
    links.reduce((acc, el) => {
      if (el.parent === "1") {
        acc[el.id] = {
          ...el,
          children: []
        };
      } else {
        acc[el.parent].children.push(el);
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );
```

The nested links are pushed into a `children` property.

Update the `toggle` state and logic so the UI isn't toggling ***all*** the submenus open together. The following stores the link `id` of a menu that has been toggled open. The `toggleSubmenu` handler allows the submenu to be opened without allowing the parent navigation to occur.

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState({});

const toggleSubmenu = (id) => (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  setToggle((ids) => ({
    ...ids,
    [id]: !ids[id]
  }));
};
```

Next is to update the render to map these `children` links.

```
const ort = createLinks(orter).map((obj) => {
  return (
    <ul className="nav-links">
      <li parentid={obj.parent} key={obj.id}>
        <Link to={obj.url}>
          <i className="knapp">#</i>
          <span className="link_name">{obj.rubrik}</span>{" "}
          <i className="arrow" onClick={toggleSubmenu(obj.id)}>
            [sub]
          </i>
        </Link>
        {toggle[obj.id] && ( // <-- check if id is toggled true
          <ul className="sub-menu">
            {obj.children.map((nestedObj) => ( // <-- render children links
              <li key={nestedObj.id}>
                <Link to={nestedObj.url}>{nestedObj.rubrik}</Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
});

return <div className="sidebar">{ort}</div>;
```

[image: Edit react-submenus-from-an-array]

[image]

Comment: Hey,

Sorry for my late reply but got struck by covid the day after I posted this.
I've tried to implement this solution now, but I get a type error.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children')"
At line Nav.jsx 15
Here is the code:
const createLinks = (links) =>
Object.values(
    links.reduce((acc, el) => {
        if(el.parent === '1'){
            acc[el.id] = {
                ...el,
                children:[]
            }
        } else {
            acc[el.parent].children.push(el)
        }
        return acc;
    }, {})
)

Comment: I fixed this error by following jakes answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080597/%C3%97-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map

I put a question mark in at line 15 after the array: else {
            acc[el.parent]?.children.push(el)
        }

Not entirely sure why this works but hey it works. xD

Comment: @SvantePålsson No worries, hopefully you've recovered and are well now. Yes, it's the [Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) useful when accessing into potentially null or undefined properties. The code in my solution *should* always create a `children` property to iterate over... but I think I do see a potential issue regarding parent nodes and the order of the original data. I think I made assumptions that a parent node would always appear and be processed prior to children nodes.

Comment: @SvantePålsson If my answer is currently sufficient for you, then cheers and good luck. If not, then can you include the data and code you were using when you hit that issue and we can optimize for that?

Comment: Hey Drew. :)
Your code worked flawlessly for me when I added that questionmark after acc[el.parent]. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @SvantePålsson Awesome! Welcome. Cheers and good luck!