# Uncaught TypeError from map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This function is not working properly and is showing this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

```
{users.map((users) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Name : {users.name}</h2>
      <p>Age : {users.age}</p>
      <button onClick={() => { updateUser(users.id) }}>Ince Age</button>
      <button onClick={() => { deleteUser(users.id) }}>delete Age</button>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [× TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080597/%c3%97-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map)

Comment: Can you show some more code, where you are filling the data in users ?

Answer (score 0):

Add condition like this

if you are using Optional chaining (?.)

```
{users?.map?.((users) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Name : {users.name}</h2>
      <p>Age : {users.age}</p>
      <button onClick={() => { updateUser(users.id) }}>Ince Age</button>
      <button onClick={() => { deleteUser(users.id) }}>delete Age</button>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

else

```
{users && users.length > 0 && users.map((users) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Name : {users.name}</h2>
      <p>Age : {users.age}</p>
      <button onClick={() => { updateUser(users.id) }}>Ince Age</button>
      <button onClick={() => { deleteUser(users.id) }}>delete Age</button>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Answer (score -1):

add `key={users.id}` inside your first div tag