# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[This is Cards components where error is being showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b2KC.png)
[This is error shown by the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjDoH.png)

trying to map data with api call but there is error in mapping .Trying to resolve it for very long time, Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: it appears that `courses[category]` is undefined. Since you don't show us what either `courses` or `category` are at the point you get the error, that's the limit of anyone being able to help at the moment.

Comment: The return value of your `getCourses()` function is returning undefined. You are passing both `courses` and `category` as props. I recommend verifying that you are correctly setting and accessing your component properties from wherever you are implementing the `Cards` component.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to come from there:

```
getCourses().map((course) => (
  <Card key={course.id}
    course={course}
    likedCourses={likedCourses}
    setLikedCourses={setLikedCourses}
  />
))
```

According to me, the call to `getCourses` returns `undefined`.

Since you either return `allCourses` or `courses[category]` from that function, I'd say that you sometimes call your `Cards` component with a `category` that is not present in your `courses` object.

You can find more information in a similar post: [× TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080597/%C3%97-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map).