React sort REST API response data alphabetically before map
Here is my code that fetches API response which I want to sort as per requirement,
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function DataList( props ) {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [objData, setObjData] = useState({});

    useEffect( ()=>{
        setIsLoading(true);
        fetch("https://dummyjson.com/product")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((json)=>{
            setObjData(json);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
    }, [] );
    console.log(objData);

  return (
    <div>
        <h1><u><i>Data List</i></u></h1>
        
        <table border="1" cellPadding={5} width={500}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Thumbnail</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan={4}>{isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : null}</td>
            </tr>
                {
                    // @ref:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080597/%C3%97-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map
                    objData['products']?.map((product) => {
                        return <tr key={product.id}>
                            <td>{product.title}</td>
                            <td>{product.brand}</td>
                            <td>{product.price}</td>
                            <td align='center'>
                                <img src={product.thumbnail} alt={product.title} width={100} />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    })
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DataList

And here is the response format



objData['products']?.slice().sort((a,b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)).map(x => ...) ?  As the sort works inplace, do a slice first, to not mutate the state variable ...

Or you could sort your data before you do setObjData ie json['products']?.sort((a,b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)); setObjData(json);

@derpirscher
I tried
.then((json)=>{
json['products']?.sort((a,b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)); setObjData(json);
setObjData(json);
setIsLoading(false);
})
Also
objData['products']?.slice().sort((a,b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)).map((product) => {
sort does not work..!

"sort does not work"  That's quite a bold statement, and I can guarantee you, sort works if you use it correctly.  Attach a breakpoint and check your data directly before you sort and directly after and compare the data. One possibility is that you are manipulating your state somewhere else ...

@derpirscher has the correct suggestion, but it's unclear what exactly you need sorted, and where and how. Based on title I'd suggest sorting inline when rendering (or memoizing a sorted list, or better yet, sort it before saving into state) but you neglected to mention what you want to sort by, e.g. brand? category? description? title? etc? and haven't shown what you've tried on your own already.

You can use Array.prototype.toSorted() now its supported by all the browsers MDN
The toSorted() method of Array instances is the copying version of the sort() method. It returns a new array with the elements sorted order.
I've tested this, works for me, also changed the objData directly to an array.
import React ,{ useEffect, useState }from 'react';

function DataList( props ) {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [objData, setObjData] = useState(null);

    useEffect( ()=>{
        setIsLoading(true);
        fetch("https://dummyjson.com/product")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((json)=>{
          console.log(json)
            const data = json.products.toSorted((a,b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
            console.log(data);
            setObjData(data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }).catch(console.warn)
    }, [] );
    console.log(objData);

  return (
    <div>
        <h1><u><i>Data List</i></u></h1>
        
        <table border="1" cellPadding={5} width={500}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Thumbnail</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan={4}>{isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : null}</td>
            </tr>
                {
                    // @ref:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080597/%C3%97-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map
                    objData?.map((product) => {
                        return <tr key={product.id}>
                            <td>{product.title}</td>
                            <td>{product.brand}</td>
                            <td>{product.price}</td>
                            <td align='center'>
                                <img src={product.thumbnail} alt={product.title} width={100} />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    })
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  )
}


Your approach will lose the first level of the api result. Ie it will directly set objData as the prodcuts array instead of the object containing the prodcuts array. Thus at rendering, objData['prodcuts'] will be undefined ...

@derpirscher thats why i changed that to objData?.map, you can see there why down vote?

I think you didn't see that @derpirscher

Then you should at least mention that in your answer. Because silently changing OP's datamodel will lead to additional errors ...
